# Uploading local file to GraphDB

Tags: file-upload, graphdb, turtle-rdf

Tried the following curl command for uploading a local turtle file to GraphDB (free version), running at `http://localhost:7200/`.

`curl -X POST 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/testrepository1/statements' -H "Content-Type:text/turtle" -T "/home/Desktop/onto.ttl"`

Eventhough this curl command doesn't return any error when executed, the local file `onto.ttl` is not uploaded to `testrepository1`

Iam using graphDB free with version 9.7.0.

It'll be grateful if someone help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong mime type - it should be application/x-turtle instead of text/turtle. The request will look something like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-turtle" -T "/home/Desktop/onto.ttl" http://localhost:7200/repositories/testrepository1/statements
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it now, but it didn't work either. May I know whether we have to use a separate command to upload the file first or upload and import will be handled in this single command?
Also, what version of graphDB are you using?

Comment: This should be enough to upload the file. Could you run the curl above with verbose (-v parameter) and send the output? The version shouldn't matter in this case.